# eclipse javascript plugins to detect inheritance

Tags: javascript, eclipse, inheritance, content-assist, jsdt

My project implemets inheritance via following code pattern:

```
ScanTemplate1.prototype = Object.create(ScanTemplateBase.prototype);
ScanTemplate1.prototype.contructor = ScanTemplate1;
```

Here, ScanTemplate1 inherits from ScanTemplateBase class.

Now in any .js file, content assist only suggests member functions defined in ScanTemplate1.js file. It doesn't suggest member functions inherited from ScanTemplateBase.

I am using eclipse Luna with latest JSDT version. **Is there a way to enable content assist to suggest inherited member functions?**

**Example:**
ScanTemplateBase class has a function

```
ScanTemplateBase.prototype.getInstruction = function(){
    return this.instruction;
};
```

ScanTemplate1 has a function

```
ScanTemplate1.prototype.getTextbox = function() {
return this.textbox;
};
```

Now, in a file **main.js**, I have statement

```
var packageScanBox = new ScanTemplate1( ..... constructor args ....);
```

On typing **packageScanBox.** and pressing **Ctrl + space**, it suggests *getTextbox()* but not *getInstruction()*

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disclaimer, I'm the author of [tern.java](https://github.com/angelozerr/tern.java/)

I suggest you that you [install tern.java](https://github.com/angelozerr/tern.java/wiki/Installation-Update-Site) which supports `Object.create`. I have tested quickly :

[image]

As tern.java is based on [ternjs](http://ternjs.net/), you can test your case with [ternjs online demo](http://ternjs.net/doc/demo.html).

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion Angelo! I tried installing tern but it doesn't seem to be working. I installed 3 things:
1. Tern feature
2. Tern JSDT feature
3. Tern Linters
Then i converted project to Tern and in Properties->tern->Modules , the completion guess is checked.
But content assist shows no additional suggestions. If I press Ctrl+Space again, it says "No Tern Completion Proposal Category"

Comment: You need to install "Tern - Embed Node.js" too if you have not node installed, because ternjs is executed by node.

Comment: Now it is trying to fetch proposals from tern server and then errors out with a long message, part of which is "The extension took too long to return from the 'computeCompleteProposals()' operation.
Does it need to contact a server for every proposal? Because that will be slow anyway

Comment: The error message also said to remove plugin from word proposals list, after I did, it started working!!!

Comment: ternjs can be slow if you load a lot of JS files (on the first time). If you install 1.0.0-SNAPSHOT you can exclude path https://github.com/angelozerr/tern.java/wiki/New-and-Noteworthy-1.0.0#includeexclude-tern-script-paths